# Menu items not appearing when base item is 'current'

Tags: menu

I might be missing something very basic here but this is really confusing me. I have the following Menu structure:

```
|-Honda
|-Honda|-Civic
|-Honda|-Hybrid
|-Honda|-Used
```

I have a Menu Module called 'Honda' with the above Menu and the base item is 'Current'. This module is displayed on the left and when I am on Civic page, it shows something like this:

```
|- Honda
    -- **Civic**
    -- Hybrid
```

But when I am on the Honda Used page, it just shows this:

```
->Honda
```

I was expecting something like the following:

```
-- Honda
    -- Used
```

I checked the HTML source and it only seems to have generated the li for the first level (or Honda). I am using Joomla 3.2 and was wondering if I am being daft or is there some issue here. Thank you.

Comment: Got a URL to have a quick peep at? I am being dense and your examples are not clear so I would like to see the problem live so to speak

Comment: Sorry MorganUK for the late reply. Still trying to figure out the issue so that I can explain it properly. Looks more and more like a big. But will update it as soon as I can figure out how to best 'phrase' the question. Thanks.

Comment: Whenever you have the time

Comment: Please post your module configuration and make sure it's not a 3rd-party problem by deactivating template overrides.

Comment: By Module Configuration things like 'Select Menu', 'Base Item', 'Start Level', 'End Level' and such I presume?

The menu Item in question [where the Menu Item is not appearing] is a third party component but since I have no  Overrides (just CSS adjustments), I am a bit confused as to how this might happen.

I also have another Menu Module loaded horizontally and it seems to load fine. Still, if you could let me know what module configuration I might post; I will try to get a screengrab of it. Thanks.